# Wii DVD drive disassembly and reassembly

Tags: nintendo-wii, hardware

Can someone please tell me how I can properly disassemble and reassemble a Nintendo Wii DVD disc drive?

I know someone by the name 'Console Zombie' has posted [a tutorial on YouTube](http://youtu.be/0DRhKC9x9ZY) for the Wii U version.

But is it the same concept or completely different for a Wii? My specific problem is that I took the disc drive apart because I was interested about how it worked, but I couldn't put it back together. Taking it apart seemed too easy compared to putting it back together.

This is the current state of the drive and what parts needs to be reinserted.

[image: Current State Top]

Update: The other images have been uploaded to Google Drive because they were too big for the default image upload system.

[Disc Drive Circuit Board (PCB?)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXScwVjf8gtY281TGRPQTAzdk0/view?usp=sharing)

[Disc Guidance Piece](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXScwVjf8gtWTFRZDZEaVljWjQ/view?usp=sharing)

[Motor Mechanics - Top](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXScwVjf8gtNXlHMGRBZUFuRkk/view?usp=sharing)

[Motor Mechanics - Bottom](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXScwVjf8gtRENOTWM1ZzlLM0U/view?usp=sharing)

Please excuse my bad terms for the parts. I can't remember their proper names.

Comment: This seems like it might be outside of our scope. It's brushing into EE territory in my opinion.

Comment: What is EE territory?

Comment: Electrical Engineering. There are some very smart people on that SE and this kind of question might be a good fit over there. I'm not intimately familiar with their rules so you might want to make sure before you ask over there

Comment: @twobugs I don't think it's on-topic over there either, see [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think this would fall into "Game Specific Hardware and Utilities" in this site's list of acceptable question topics. However, this question currently doesn't seem to describe a specific problem to be fixed. Could you add more detail regarding what you are trying to solve and where you are having trouble?

Comment: I've answered hardware related questions like this (but not for the Wii U) and I've never seen issues with those questions.

Comment: Also: See here (https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Wii+DVD+Drive+Replacement/5164) This is the answer which you are looking for.

Comment: Hi RJH, isn't that just replacing the drive, not repairing it...